# What happens to questions that are closed?

Tags: support

The FAQ didn't seem to indicate what the [closed] status indicates when applied to a question.  Aside from the obvious (such as additional answers are not allowed), what happens to them?  Do they eventually get deleted?

Here's an example:
[What are some programming design patterns that are useful in game development?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/what-are-some-programming-design-patterns-that-are-useful-in-game-development/4161#4161)

This question was closed back in January, but it's still around...

Comment: Do note that closed questions can still be useful. We still have [useful](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/) [information](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/854/) [available](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/497/) in closed questions - they're just closed whilst leaving the information available for people searching for it.

Answer (score 2):

[Do closed questions ever get deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/do-closed-questions-ever-get-deleted)

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/the-stack-overflow-question-lifecycle/